# Rails dynamic javascript loading

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing, dynamic-loading, revolution-slider

In RoR, How do you dynamicaly load .js files located in your own rails server via ajax calls?
How do you define the route to that .js files?

I going to try to explain the situation I'm trying to solve.

I'm trying to use rails with one of the html templates of "revolution slider" from "ThemePunch" as my "index.html.erb".

Basically the template adds a "revolution.js" that "dynamically" load another .js files (or "extensions") via ajax calls.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to define a route to this .js extension files or its directory. I'm getting a "get routing error".

Could I define a route to one directory and not to a controller?
Something like:     get 'revolution/extensions/*', to: render(/app/revolution/extensions/*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the deal , you see what a route call does is take the call to an action on controller and based upon result return option set by the action it returns the view or data.

In your case , you can first,

1. ajax call an route
2. Route will go to a controller action.
3. - Action can load up some.js.erb file with script written on it.    OR,
   - Action can render up a html template with js loaded over it but same time you may need to manipulate the main view page with js to show the slider as you mentioned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Mahabub.

Comment: Following your advice I finally got it. I must place the js files under the views directory. Thanks.

Comment: well its not a decent way to do it. but it will work for now. just be sure to assign them over turbolink asset preload to make app load faster. and also there are other ways.  Like using jquery events to trigger those specific slider related functions.  
You will find your way eventually in many good more ways. Do not forget to make sure they behave perfectly while on production. and please do not forget to mark my answer as right answer if that helped...  take care.