# Recommend approach for adding javascript from Ruby On Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Gem that adds extra functionality to ActiveRecords. During installation, someone has to add the following to their form's erb file to get extra form elements provided by my gem:

```
<%= render "forms/my_gem", form: f %>
```

What is the best way to handle adding javascript inside my view file?  I hate to have this javascript be used on every page, so I was wondering if the best approach is to add inline javascript. If you know of a gem that does this, can you please share.

Comment: What about providing the .js file name as an option, where your core gem implementation doing dynamic requiring and loading whenever it is provided?

Comment: This might be helpful 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108366/rails-dynamic-javascript-loading

Comment: @zauzaj Do you have an example of dynamic requiring of JS?